# Wait for element to be appeared in the dom and then execute code angular 6 unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, typescript2.0

I need to wait for element to be loaded in the dom, so that I need to check the text string it contains.

I tried so far, `fixture.whenStable().then` but didn't work. How can I wait for the element until it loads in the dom.

```
it( 'should change the text value for the element', function() {
    let testDropdown : HTMLElement;
    const debugElement : DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    testDropdown = debugElement.queryAll( By.css( 'mat-select' ) )[ 0 ].nativeElement;
    testDropdown.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    debugElement.queryAll( By.css( 'mat-option' ) )[ 1 ].nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect( testDropdown.getAttribute( 'ng-reflect-value' ) ).toEqual( 'Text 2' );
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const elementTitle = debugElement.queryAll( By.css( '.legend' ) );
    console.log( elementTitle );
} );
```

Once I change the select option, the same select option text, I am setting to legend element. I need to wait for that legend item to be loaded. That element will be loaded asynchronously.

Any suggestions? How can I proceed?

Comment: provide `component` and `spec` file code, so that we can see what have been implemented from your end

Comment: @ShashankVivek added the some sample code, please check. Let me know, if still needed more info

Comment: Please add your ```component```, too. What is the reason you trigger the change detection after each expect?